# How can I change fonts within the sciposter class?

Tags: fonts, sciposter

It seems like the font choice is somehow embedded in the document class itself; I've tried choosing fonts the usual way, but with no effect.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem, showing what you tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: @doncherry:  Ah, alright.  I've seen MWEs on questions I've read before, but I didn't realize they were actually standard/required!  Luckily, your renewcommand did the trick.

Comment: They're definitely good style, and probably even essential for most questions. They definitely make it easier for other users to answer your questions, and perhaps tell potential answerers what the problem might be, just like here: A package like `libertine` works fine, others don't; so actually your question was imprecise in a way -- for _some_ font packages "the usual way" works, for others it doesn't. Another policy-kind of thing here: It's good style not only to accept the answer that helped you most, but also to upvote ([faq#howtoask]) answers that you found helpful.

Comment: @donecherry: Thanks!  Apparently I need 15 reputation points to upvote, but I'll come back and do it if and when that happens...

Comment: Of course, I forgot about that, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{sciposter}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\Huge Hello
\end{document}
```

The problem might be that you loaded a font package that doesn't provide a sans-serif font, e.g. `mathpazo` or `fourier`. In that case you need to add the following to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
```

This makes the serif font the default font. The standard for `sciposter` is to use the sans-serif font as default.

Answer (score 5):

The class loads the (obsolete) package `times` and sets the default font family to sans serif (Helvetica).

If you want to use, say, the Computer Modern fonts, you have to revert the setting:

```
\documentclass{sciposter}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
```

However, as `sciposter` uses big font sizes, a scalable font may be better:

```
\documentclass{sciposter}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Alternatively, you can load a different font package:

```
\documentclass{sciposter}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
```

or any font package of your choice.

Comment: +1 This answer is extremely useful as it gives all the different options for changing fonts.