# I can't get my text to be italic on a poster

Tags: italic, posters, sciposter

There is a few words that I want to make italic/ emphasized on a poster. I have tried `\textit{State}`, `\it{State}`, `{\itshape State}`, and `\emph{State}` and nothing works. I am using `\usepackage{garamond}` in my preamble. I don't know if that's what's affecting it or not. Please help.

Here's some of the file:

Thank you! Here's the file:

```
\documentclass[landscape,custom]{sciposter}
\usepackage[all,poly]{xy}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphpap,setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{problem}[thm]{Problem}
\newtheorem{alg}[thm]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
%\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\definecolor{BoxCol}{rgb}{0,.44,.53}
\definecolor{SectionCol}{rgb}{1,1,1}

\usepackage{garamond}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\title{Predicting the Future of Coral Reefs: A Simulation Approach}
\author{Chelsey Beese}
\institute{Department of Mathematics and Statistics}
\date{}
\leftlogo[1.5]{CCU}
\conference{{\bf Math 490}}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\topsep}{2ex}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{3}

\section{Model Set Up and Initialization}

The spatial domain consists of a 2500 by 2500 grid of $1 \mbox{ cm}^2$ 
regular hexagonal cells covering a total area of $625 \mbox{ m}^2$.
Each cell is inhabited by a single organism, denoted by the
%HERE'S WHERE I WANT THE ITALICS%
\texit{cell state}, which can vary over time based on stochastic rules and
the inhabitants of neighboring cells. Cell states are updated on a yearly
basis. The cell size reflects the approximate size of a single coral polyp
rather than imposing an unnatural scale on the system \cite{Soong1993}.
Corals are colonial organisms composed of a group of individual fleshy
polyps that are connected by a layer of thin connective tissue and secrete
a common calcareous skeleton. Therefore, a single organism can span
multiple cells.

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Sorry everyone, I'm really new to all of this!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) (mininum working example, starting with `\begin{document}` and ending with `\end{document}`) that shows what you've done so far and illustrates where things aren't going to your plans. Incidentally, if you add backticks around code snippets, they will be autoformatted as such.

Comment: As far as I'm aware `garamond` has been superceded by `garamondx`, not sure if that's related. This is a case where the robotic response is right; it would be very useful to have a minimal working example.

Comment: Look at your `.log` file and search for warnings about automatic font substitutions (which happen when the requested shape/series is not availabie in the current family). This would provide a hint of the problem.

Comment: The is not an MWE, please also post the full preamble

Comment: After searching in the .log, the exact warning you mentioned showed up. It said: LaTeX font warning: Some font shapes were not available, default substituted. Is there a way I can fix this? I tried switching to garamondx but it did not work.

Comment: @Chelsey: You should probably use `\textit`, not `\texit`...

Comment: Oops! I did use \textit, must have been an edit when I was posting the file. I took out a lot of the stuff because the file is very long. Even spelled correctly, the command doesn't work. The .log file told me why, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Chelsey Garamond package/fonts are not installed by default in my system. A google search reveals that there are several options for using Garamond, but I don't know which one are you using. You should provide the source of `garamond.sty` to give more clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get your code to work by making the two following edits:

1. I couldn't find the `garamond` package, but I did manage to find and use the `ebgaramond` package instead.
2. As @Werner pointed out, you mean to use the command `\textit` and not the misspelling `\texit`.

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[landscape,custom]{sciposter}
\usepackage[all,poly]{xy}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphpap,setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{problem}[thm]{Problem}
\newtheorem{alg}[thm]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
%\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\definecolor{BoxCol}{rgb}{0,.44,.53}
\definecolor{SectionCol}{rgb}{1,1,1}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\title{Predicting the Future of Coral Reefs: A Simulation Approach}
\author{Chelsey Beese}
\institute{Department of Mathematics and Statistics}
\date{}
%\leftlogo[1.5]{CCU}
\conference{{\bf Math 490}}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\topsep}{2ex}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{3}

\section{Model Set Up and Initialization}

The spatial domain consists of a 2500 by 2500 grid of $1 \mbox{ cm}^2$ 
regular hexagonal cells covering a total area of $625 \mbox{ m}^2$.
Each cell is inhabited by a single organism, denoted by the
%HERE'S WHERE I WANT THE ITALICS%
\textit{cell state}, which can vary over time based on stochastic rules and
the inhabitants of neighboring cells. Cell states are updated on a yearly
basis. The cell size reflects the approximate size of a single coral polyp
rather than imposing an unnatural scale on the system \cite{Soong1993}.
Corals are colonial organisms composed of a group of individual fleshy
polyps that are connected by a layer of thin connective tissue and secrete
a common calcareous skeleton. Therefore, a single organism can span
multiple cells.

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

## Edited

In response to your comment, you are right, I didn't realize that the `sciposter` class uses the sans serif font family by default.

The following MWE is able to override the default font family to `ebgaramond`.

```
\documentclass{sciposter}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}

This is a test.

\end{document}
```

Here is the correct edited code which I also trimmed down:

```
\documentclass[landscape,custom]{sciposter}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\title{Predicting the Future of Coral Reefs: A Simulation Approach}
\author{Chelsey Beese}
\institute{Department of Mathematics and Statistics}
\date{}
%\leftlogo[1.5]{CCU}
\conference{{\bf Math 490}}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\topsep}{2ex}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{3}

\section{Model Set Up and Initialization}

The spatial domain consists of a 2500 by 2500 grid of $1 \mbox{ cm}^2$ 
regular hexagonal cells covering a total area of $625 \mbox{ m}^2$.
Each cell is inhabited by a single organism, denoted by the
%HERE'S WHERE I WANT THE ITALICS%
\textit{cell state}, which can vary over time based on stochastic rules and
the inhabitants of neighboring cells. Cell states are updated on a yearly
basis. The cell size reflects the approximate size of a single coral polyp
rather than imposing an unnatural scale on the system \cite{Soong1993}.
Corals are colonial organisms composed of a group of individual fleshy
polyps that are connected by a layer of thin connective tissue and secrete
a common calcareous skeleton. Therefore, a single organism can span
multiple cells.

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried using this code though, and the font that ended up on my poster was not garamond it was just the default. I'm probably doing something stupid, but I'm new to Tex.

Comment: No, you didn't do anything stupid, you're correct that the font is the default rather than `ebgaramond`. It turns out that you have to use a trick to redefine the default font for the `sciposter` class. I used the technique illustrated in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60116/how-can-i-change-fonts-within-the-sciposter-class/60120#60120 The corrected code should work now. Good luck with your LaTeX poster!

Comment: Chelsey, if indeed my answer resolves your question, could you please accept the answer? Basically you click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more information about how accepting an answer works on stack exchange.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH! Sorry it took me so long to accept it, Christmas put a halt on my work!

Comment: I understand. Merry Christmas and Happy Holidays! :-)